# Bug in the SSIS BIDS File System Task Editor?

Tags: bids, ssis-2012

1. Add a parameter to your package. Scope is not important. Set the **Sensitive** property to True.
2. Add a new File System Task to your package.
3. Double click to open the editor.
4. Set IsDestinationPathVariable = True
5. Attempt to set the property DestinationVariable.

You will see that the dialog box closes (crashes?) and you can **never** enter the variable.
It works fine for the SourceVariable property.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this does look like a bug. However, I've found that if you open the Properties box for the File System Task, you can manually type in the variable name in the `Destination` property in the form `User::VARNAME`. Not an ideal workaround, but better than having to remove sensitive parameters during development.